# Store maps in template class by reference

Tags: c++, templates, reference

So lately I learnt how to copy a map's reference and the next step is that I want to store map references in a template class.

So in my main method my goal is to create map_storage where I store my maps and do different calculations on them.

**Template class**:

```
#include <map>
#include <compare>
#include <utility>

#ifndef MAPALIGN_H
#define MAPALIGN_H

template<class Key, class T, class Compare = std::less<Key> >
class map_storage
{
public:
    map_storage() : size_(0), data_(new std::map<Key, T, Compare>[100]){}
    
    void add(std::map<Key, T, Compare> &temp_map)
    {
        data_[size_] = temp_map;
        size_ += 1;
    }

    void action(){
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Size on action " << size_ << std::endl;
        for(int i=0; i<size_; i++){
            print_map(data_[i]);
        }
    }

    void print_map(std::map<Key, T, Compare> &temp_map){
        std::cout << "Size of given map is : " << temp_map.size() << std::endl;
    }
    
    void modifyMaps(..){
        ....
    }
private:
    int size_;
    std::map<Key, T, Compare>* data_; 
    
};
#endif
```

When I modify the maps in data_ (add new key,values etc.) I want to see the changes in main too and the same thing for the other way around.

My question is that How can I store the references of the maps in a template class?

**Example of the main method:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mapalign.h"
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{
  std::map<std::string, int> map1;
  
  maps_storage<std::stringm int> maps_storage;
  
  maps_storage.add(map1);
  
  map1["asd"] = 1;
  map1["dsa"] = 2;
  
  // This should print 1 and 2 but prints 1 and 0 because the map is not in the map_storage by reference.
  map_storage.action();
    

  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
0
```

**Expected Output:**

```
1
2
```

Comment: First thing first, why are you using `new[]`? `std::vector` is your friend.

Comment: Yees I was thinking about that but the first example code I've seen was with new.

Comment: To the question. You cannot have an array of references, nor a vector of references, nor references that can be reset. You can use pointers instead, si that your class stores `std::map<std::string, int> *`. I however would recommend against this entire idea. Don't store non-owning pointers permanently.

Comment: As @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. implied, drop the pointer: `std::vector<std::map<Key, T, Compare>> data_;` - done! If you want references to individual maps in the vector, that's easy: `auto& map1 = maps_storage[0];` (assuming you implement `operator[]`)